# error: an application with the same package but a different signature after uninstall

Tags: android

I'm new in android and writing an application for my personal use. I've installed it using unsigned APK, but windows reinstallation I get the error: "an application with the same package but a different signature" I found out that the problem appears because Android studio used self-generated certificate, that was updated with new Windows.

**The problem is**: I've uninstalled this application from my phone. But I still get this error while trying to debug on the phone from IDEA. Moreover, I can not install my app from apk file. Get an error: App not installed

**Update 1**: 
`adb uninstall <your-package-name>` has not helped. I still see the above error. But there is an interesting observation: When I try to uninstall the old version of my application with `adb uninstall` - it gives me a success message instantly.

But if I execute `adb uninstall` after I try to install the new version (and get an error App not installed), in that case `adb uninstall` hangs for forever

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the app by using adb in terminal (can be cmd or terminal tab in Android Studio):

```
adb uninstall <your-package-name>
```

Then try to build and run your app in Android Studio

Comment: can you be more technical. Why it hasn't helped? refer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53zkBvL4ZB4

Comment: I've mistakenly pressed enter in the middle of the post. I've updated the post itself. Please check it

Comment: adb shell dumpsys package <package-name>

Comment: try with different device or emulator. Is anything wrong with your device?

Comment: `adb shell dumpsys package <package-name>` gives me a lot of information. What should I pay attention to?

Comment: that is the main phone I'm using. Even it will work on another device - I'd like to make it work on my main phone. That's Samsung s8. Haven't noticed anything wrong with it before

Comment: if you can spot your app in launcher or settings, try to uninstall from there?

Comment: no, it disappeared from the application list in my phone. But when I install the old version - I can remove it as a regular application from my phone. But if I try to install new version after that - I still get the above error

Comment: A little update: I'm able to install the new version by changing the package name. So the problem is not in my app